# Stored Procedure "spins" when executed from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have written 3 stored procedures and all run fine when executed in SQL Server.  However, when I execute them in Visual Studio 2012 they just "spin", creating locks, etc.  Any ideas?

Here is one of them.  Another one is selecting values from an inline view based on the same SQL and not inserting into #temp

```
    @StartDate      As DateTime,
    @EndDate        As DateTime,
    @EmployeeCode   As VarChar(50) = NULL 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


select * into #temp
from 
(SELECT e.Code AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
   e.FirstName AS FIRST_NAME,
   e.LastName AS LAST_NAME,
   ec1.TransactionDate AS DATE_OF_SHIFT,
   ou.Code AS DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
   CASE
       WHEN ec1.Classification = '1' THEN
           MIN(ec1.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_IN,
   CASE
       WHEN ec2.Classification = '2' THEN
           MAX(ec2.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_OUT,
   pc.code,
   epb.hourvalue 
FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e (nolock)
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec1 (nolock)
    ON ec1.EmployeeID = e.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec2 (nolock)
    ON ec1.OutClockingGuid = ec2.Guid
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou (nolock)
    ON ec1.OrganizationUnitID = ou.ID
LEFT JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeePremiumBucket epb (nolock)
    ON ec1.Guid = epb.TransactionGuid
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.PayCode pc (nolock)
    ON epb.PayCodeID = pc.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.PayGroupInstance pgi (nolock)
    ON pgi.ID = epb.PayGroupInstanceID
WHERE 

ec1.transactiondate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and epb.PaymentClassification = '1'
AND e.code = @EmployeeCode   

    AND e.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(e2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE e2.ID = e.ID
)
GROUP BY e.Code,
     e.FirstName,
     e.LastName,
     ec1.TransactionDate,
     ou.Code,
     ec1.Classification,
     ec2.Classification,
     pc.code,
     epb.hourvalue

UNION
SELECT e.Code AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
   e.FirstName AS FIRST_NAME,
   e.LastName AS LAST_NAME,
   ec1.TransactionDate AS DATE_OF_SHIFT,
   ou.Code AS DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
   CASE
       WHEN ec1.Classification = '1' THEN
           MIN(ec1.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_IN,
   CASE
       WHEN ec2.Classification = '2' THEN
           MAX(ec2.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_OUT,
   pc.code,
   epb.hourvalue 
FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e (nolock)
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec1 (nolock)
    ON ec1.EmployeeID = e.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec2 (nolock)
    ON ec1.OutClockingGuid = ec2.Guid
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou (nolock)
    ON ec1.OrganizationUnitID = ou.ID
LEFT JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeePremiumBucket epb (nolock)
    ON ec1.Guid = epb.TransactionGuid
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayCode pc (nolock)
    ON epb.PayCodeID = pc.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayGroupInstance pgi (nolock)
    ON pgi.ID = epb.PayGroupInstanceID
WHERE 
ec1.transactiondate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and epb.PaymentClassification = '1'
AND e.code = @EmployeeCode     
AND e.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(e2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE e2.ID = e.ID
)
AND ou.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(ou2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE ou2.ID = ou.ID
)
AND pc.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(pc2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayCode pc2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE pc2.ID = pc.ID
)
                             
GROUP BY e.Code,
     e.FirstName,
     e.LastName,
     ec1.TransactionDate,
     ou.Code,
     ec1.Classification,
     ec2.Classification,
     pc.code,
     epb.hourvalue) as X

select EMPLOYEE_ID, 
FIRST_NAME, 
LAST_NAME,
DATE_OF_SHIFT, 
DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
CLOCK_IN, 
CLOCK_OUT, 
code, 
sum(hourvalue) as Hours
from #temp
group by EMPLOYEE_ID,
FIRST_NAME,
LAST_NAME,
DATE_OF_SHIFT,
DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
CLOCK_IN,
CLOCK_OUT,
CODE
Order by CLOCK_OUT
END
```

---

---

Here is the other one.

```
    @StartDate      As DateTime,
    @EndDate        As DateTime,
    @EmployeeCode   As VarChar(50) = NULL 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


select EMPLOYEE_ID, 
FIRST_NAME, 
LAST_NAME,
DATE_OF_SHIFT, 
DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
CLOCK_IN, 
CLOCK_OUT, 
code, 
sum(hourvalue) as Hours
from 
(
SELECT e.Code AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
   e.FirstName AS FIRST_NAME,
   e.LastName AS LAST_NAME,
   ec1.TransactionDate AS DATE_OF_SHIFT,
   ou.Code AS DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
   CASE
       WHEN ec1.Classification = '1' THEN
           MIN(ec1.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_IN,
   CASE
       WHEN ec2.Classification = '2' THEN
           MAX(ec2.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_OUT,
   pc.code,
   epb.hourvalue 
FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec1
    ON ec1.EmployeeID = e.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec2
    ON ec1.OutClockingGuid = ec2.Guid
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou
    ON ec1.OrganizationUnitID = ou.ID
LEFT JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.EmployeePremiumBucket epb
    ON ec1.Guid = epb.TransactionGuid
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.PayCode pc
    ON epb.PayCodeID = pc.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_Live.dbo.PayGroupInstance pgi
    ON pgi.ID = epb.PayGroupInstanceID
WHERE ec1.transactiondate between @StartDate and @EndDate 
and epb.PaymentClassification = '1'
AND e.code = @EmployeeCode
AND e.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(e2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE e2.ID = e.ID
)
GROUP BY e.Code,
     e.FirstName,
     e.LastName,
     ec1.TransactionDate,
     ou.Code,
     ec1.Classification,
     ec2.Classification,
     pc.code,
     epb.hourvalue

UNION
SELECT e.Code AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
   e.FirstName AS FIRST_NAME,
   e.LastName AS LAST_NAME,
   ec1.TransactionDate AS DATE_OF_SHIFT,
   ou.Code AS DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
   CASE
       WHEN ec1.Classification = '1' THEN
           MIN(ec1.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_IN,
   CASE
       WHEN ec2.Classification = '2' THEN
           MAX(ec2.TransactionDate)
   END AS CLOCK_OUT,
   pc.code,
   epb.hourvalue 
FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec1
    ON ec1.EmployeeID = e.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeeClocking ec2
    ON ec1.OutClockingGuid = ec2.Guid
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou
    ON ec1.OrganizationUnitID = ou.ID
LEFT JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.EmployeePremiumBucket epb
    ON ec1.Guid = epb.TransactionGuid
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayCode pc
    ON epb.PayCodeID = pc.ID
JOIN APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayGroupInstance pgi
    ON pgi.ID = epb.PayGroupInstanceID
WHERE ec1.transactiondate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and epb.PaymentClassification = '1'
AND e.code = @EmployeeCode
AND e.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(e2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.Employee e2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE e2.ID = e.ID
)
AND ou.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(ou2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.OrganizationUnit ou2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE ou2.ID = ou.ID
)
AND pc.ArchiveTaskID =
(
    SELECT MAX(pc2.ArchiveTaskID)
    FROM APIHealthcare_History_Live.dbo.PayCode pc2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE pc2.ID = pc.ID
)
GROUP BY e.Code,
     e.FirstName,
     e.LastName,
     ec1.TransactionDate,
     ou.Code,
     ec1.Classification,
     ec2.Classification,
     pc.code,
     epb.hourvalue) as X
     
group by
EMPLOYEE_ID, 
FIRST_NAME, 
LAST_NAME,
DATE_OF_SHIFT, 
DEPT_UNIT_CODE,
CLOCK_IN, 
CLOCK_OUT, 
code 
order by date_of_shift, code 
END
```

Comment: There are "plan-affecting options" which change the way SQL Query Planner creates plans to execute queries and these can lead to major performance differences between different clients executing exactly the same SQL code. Compare the SSMS and Visual Studio settings for ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Read through Erland Sommarskog's excellent article, [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) to understand why this happens.

Comment: Does a very basic stored procedure `SELECT 1` cause the same issue? I suggest you incrementally add code until you find the part causing the issue. Or use `sp_whoisactive` to identify what type of wait is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

They are different execution environments. And yes, read Sommarskog's article already recommended.  But I think main reason why these procedures will be slow (and not consistently) is the `UNION` operator.  You should use `UNION ALL`.
Second, get rid of these (nolock) hints. They don't help you. If you **really** need that, you should use

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

at the beginning of your procedure. It does the same.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I'll give it a try and post the outcome.